# What is the real difference between GWT app and Vaadin pure-client app?

Tags: gwt, client-side, vaadin

Are there any additional binding or server-client communication techniques or any other advantage rather than using client widgets like VButton/VTextEdit e.t.c?

Comment: what do you mean by pure-client app? As far as i know it is not possible to run vaadin applications only in the browser. There is always a server side part.

Comment: @raffael, Vaadin includes GWT since version 7. So now it's possible to use com.vaadin.client subclasses to implement client-side functionality.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with your question then. I'm using vaadin 7 an knew that gwt is included, but the idea of using it only on client side never occurred to me. I think it's like not using the main advantage of vaadin. And just for those also never thought of it, there is even a chapter in the book: https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/clientsideapp.html